# Making a pointer that points to two bytes

Tags: c, pointers, i2c

I'm a complete novice in everything except maybe breathing, so sorry if I'm not being clear, but here goes:

I have a function in C which writes bytes to a circuit via an I2C bus, and in the header file it looks like this:

```
BOOL WINAPI JidaI2CWrite(HJIDA hJida, DWORD dwType, BYTE bAddr, LPBYTE pBytes, DWORD dwLen);
```

- hJida: Board handle.
- dwType: Zero-based number of the I2C
  bus.
- bAddr: Address of the device on the
  I2C bus, the full 8 bits as it is
  written to the bus.
- pBytes: Pointer to location that
  contains the bytes.
- dwLen: Number of bytes to write.

If I wanted to write just one byte to a circuit with the address 0x98, I would do something like this:

```
unsigned char writing[1];
writing[0]=0x10;

unsigned char *pointer;
pointer = &writing[0];


JidaI2CWrite(hJida,0,0x98,pointer,1);
```

which seems to work, but if I wanted to write two bytes, say 0x10FF, it doesn't. So how do I make a pointer that points to two bytes instead of just one?

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to keep up with your breathing as you read the answers :-)

Comment: Is pointer = &writing[1] a typo?  That most certainly shouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, pointer = &writing[0] is probably what you meant. Or, just "pointer = writing";

Comment: Yes in all probability it is, if its not then the JidaI2CWrite API is flawed.

Answer (score 10):

You want something like this:

```
unsigned char writing[2];
writing[0] = 0x01;
writing[1] = 0x02;

JidaI2CWrite(hJida, 0, 0x98, writing, 2);
```

Notice that an array in C can be usually be used just like a pointer.  The variable `writing` can be thought of as just a pointer to a chunk of memory that in this case has a size of 2 bytes.  Creating another pointer to point to that location is redundant (in this case).

Note you could make it point to any number of bytes:

```
unsigned char writing[12];

//fill the array with data

JidaI2CWrite(hJida, 0, 0x98, writing, 12);
```

Comment: "Notice that arrays in C are actually just pointers" not quite...see "http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html"

Comment: @SDX2000 excellent point and reference, I oversimplified, hopefully my edit is more accurate

Comment: @SDX2000 That link gives a 404

Comment: @eamsden if you remove the erroneous double-quotes at the end of the link it works

Comment: Of course, it's even better to use sizeof, and not repeat the size. The call would then look like JidaI2CWrite(hJida, 0, 0x98, writing, sizeof writing);. You could also use "sizeof writing / sizeof *writing" if you suspect the type of writing is likely to change from a char type.

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
//A buffer containing the bytes to be written
unsigned char writeBuffer[] = {0x10, 0xFF}; 

//writeBuffer itself points to the start of the write buffer
//you dont need an extra pointer variable
//Indicate the size of the buffer in the call to the function
//pointers do not carry array size information with them (in C/C++)
JidaI2CWrite(hJida,0,0x98,writeBuffer,2);
```

or better yet

```
unsigned char writeBuffer[] = {0x10, 0xFF};

JidaI2CWrite(hJida,0,0x98,writeBuffer
              ,sizeof(writeBuffer)/sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Note: `sizeof(writeBuffer)/sizeof(writeBuffer[0])` automatically calculates the size of the array in bytes for you

Comment: dividing by `sizeof(unsigned char)` is pointless, since `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 in the standard and `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(char)`

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the `dwLen` parameter is the number of bytes to write. So:

```
unsigned char writing[2];
writing[0] = 0x10;
writing[1] = 0xff;
JidaI2CWrite(hJida, 0, 0x98, writing, 2);
```

Note that your use of `pointer` pointing to `writing[1]` probably shouldn't work as written, because that sets `pointer` to point to the byte *after* the byte you really want to write. I'm suspecting this is a typo, but if not you may wish to review your existing code before proceeding.

Comment: @Greg: it might work or it might not.  The point is that the behavior of the program is *undefined* according to the language spec.

Comment: @StephenC: "undefined" in what way? Actually accessing Writing[1] may be undefined, but taking it's address should work, surely?

Answer (score 1):

`writing` is already the pointer that you want.

Get rid of `pointer`.

The final parameter to JidaI2CWrite is the number of bytes you want to to write.

The pointer `pBytes` points to the start of the block you want to write.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 choices:

1) write them separately:

writing[0] = 0x10;
writing[1] = 0xFF;

2) check if short on your system is 2Bytes and use a short.

probably as ((short*)writing)[0] = 0x10FF;

Also, you need to declaire writing is char writing[2];

and then, as others have said, write the 2 bytes...

Comment: "((short*)writing)[0] = 0x10FF;"  is calling for troubles due to endianness issues. e.g. on x86 and sparc it would give different results, and it's a pain to hunt the bugs of such kind.

Comment: having recently done such fixes in some mac code, moving from powerpc to intel, you are very very correct.